# how to pass input(type = text ) from a html form to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

i want to pass the udid taken from textfield to function getusername.

```
<tr>
     <td> Enter Udid : </td>
     <td> <input name="udid" id="udid" type="text" value="{{udid}}" size="50"></td>
</tr>

<td> 
     <input type="button" value="Get User Name(udid)" onclick="getUserName(udid);"> 
</td>
```

Comment: I am not really a pro in javascript, but i think you should pass id of the element, since u are initializing id=udid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

In your html:

```
<input type="button" value="Get User Name(udid)" onclick="getUserName(document.getElementById('udid'));">
```

Function javascript:

```
function getUserName(id){
    alert(id.value);
}
```

Look at this demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KYjjK/)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
onclick="getUserName(document.getElementById('udid').value);"
```