# Javascript Counting Customers

Tags: javascript, html, dom, math

I'm having an issue getting results with my code. I am trying to create an input box where guest can type their name and once they click the button, underneath in the DOM will appear:

`Hello, ____! You are the __ customer.`

I need help on getting their name to appear and also how to get their customer number to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>X-th Customer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Please sign in to the guest book</h1>

<input type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<p class="guestName"></p>



<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var guestName = guestName;
var guestNum = num;

    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementByClass("guestName").innerHTML = "Hello, " + guestName + "! You are the " + guestNum + "!";
}
```

Comment: The customer count is something you'll have to compute and persist at the server.

Comment: You need to read the input's value. You can give it an id then use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the element then read its value.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't sending the information from the form to the function. This explains how to do that: [how to pass input(type = text ) from a html form to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401411/how-to-pass-inputtype-text-from-a-html-form-to-javascript-function)
Also, I'm not really sure what you want to do with customer number.